# How can I set Paperclip Gem image data from a file on s3, instead of from a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

The standard method for setting paperclip image data:

In your edit and new views:

<% form_for :user, @user, :url => user_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
In your controller:

def create
  @user = User.create( params[:user] )
end

However I have a whole dir of files on s3 that I want to make Image models for. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out to be pretty easy:

```
    i = Image.new
    i.image = open('/path') #requires open-uri
    i.save
```

(Image is my model, and image is the attachment attribute)